# How to check MIME type of a file while using Selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-requests, web-crawler

I am making a web crawler using Selenium in Python 3.5, the problem I am having is that while crawling it clicks on the links that are some sort of file like ".pdf" or ".zip" or ".exe". It opens them and then the "open with" dialog box appears and my program just stucks there.

I have already tried looking for these strings in the links and most of the time it works but I want 100% results. What should I do?

Edit: This is the code that checks for a good link:

```
def check(link):
    li = [".pdf", ".jpg", ".doc", ".docx", ".DOCX", ".xlsx", "xls", ".csv", ".ppt", ".png", ".gif", ".zip", ".tar", ".rar", ".dll", ".ics", ".crl", ".iso", ".txt", ".msi", ".vcs", ".asc", ".exe", ".bmp", ".wmv", ".jpeg"]
    for i in li:
        if i in link:
            return False
    if "linkedin.com" in link or "facebook.com" in link or "twitter.com" in link or "instagram.com" in link or "amazon.com" in link:
        return False
    if "google.com" in link or "?share" in link or "reddit.com" in link:
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: Please be more specific about the problem you have. If you can't detect the type from the link, perhaps try to read the mimetype in the response.

Comment: do you have any code trials ?

Comment: post your code and update your syntax

Answer (score 1):

There is no-way(most probably) to check whether a given link is of which format.
But a better way(mostly best) would be to check the MIME type of the link by making a request call to the particular link and then check the "type/subtype" of any link.

So basically after making the request.get(link) just check the MIME type equals to text/html or not. That would suffice maybe.

But request.get is a costly process to fetch just the content-type so using SESSION HEAD requests would be better.

You can use the Session.head method to create HEAD requests:

```
response = session.head(url, timeout=self.pageOpenTimeout)
contentType = response.headers['content-type']
if (contentType == "text/html") | (contentType == "multipart/form-data"):
    print("Required Link : %s" %url)
    #DO ANYTHING HERE <<  >>
```

A HEAD request similar to GET request, except that the message body would not be sent.

Popular *type/subtype*:

| type/subtype |
| --- |
| text/plain |
| text/html |
| image/jpeg |
| image/png |
| audio/mpeg |
| audio/ogg |
| audio/* |
| video/mp4 |

SOURCES : https://web.archive.org/web/20210816145541/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type

Comment: As I have mentioned in my question, I have already tried that but some of the links don't have this property.

Comment: Most of the pages do not have ".html" at the end of their URL.

Answer (score 1):

*Selenium* alone can't detect the *MIME* type of the files which gets downloaded. But you can use *Python's* [**urllib.request**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) library to access the `src` or `href` attribute and then use [**python-magic**](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic) the **python wrapper for libmagic** to check the *MIME* type.

As an example the following sample program, opens a [demo url](https://www.webscorer.com/resources/templatestart), finds the desired element, extracts the `src` attribute, requests the `headers` and detects the *MIME* types:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import urllib
  from urllib.request import urlopen
  import magic
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  mime = magic.Magic(mime=True)
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.webscorer.com/resources/templatestart")
  elemHref = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tr.rowBg-mod1 td.tmplicon>a.downloadlink>img[alt='TXT file']"))).get_attribute("src")
  request = urllib.request.Request(elemHref)
  response = urlopen(request)
  mime_type = magic.from_buffer(response.readline())
  print(mime_type)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  GIF image data, version 89a, 19 x 18
  ```

---

### trivia

Based on the *MIME* type you can write a switch block to allow automatic download.

Comment: how? any example?\